# How to identify solely or grouped services for a microservice

Tags: architecture, microservices, services

Here is an example I asked myself to better understand microservices, but the thing is, I am confused on how to identify them in this particular case.

There are cinemas in each country, 
those cinemas have a catalog of movies 
and not every movie can be listed in this catalog.
As an example, say one movie is showed only in JPN, KRN and CHN and years later is worldwide released.

From this example I understood the following

- One possible service could be *Country Service* with more details (region, district, etc)
- Another one must be *Cinema Service* (MS2)
  Basically a CRUD of cinemas
- One could say *Movies Service* (MS3) is another one but if each cinema has movies that other might not but could have in a future....

At the end this are my questions

- Would merging MS2 and MS3 be ok? would MS2 be in charge now to add its own movies?
- How could I query for movies of each cinema if I decide to have MS3 as a separate service?

Comment: No, cinemas and movies seem like fairly distinct responsibilities, which can be used by different actors.

Comment: I thought on that too. Actually, I was thinking if I keep them separate how to manage the data?. There would be two separate databases with duplicate data

Comment: Don't duplicate data - use foreign keys. Your Countries have licenses for a list of movies (by foreign key), and your Cinemas are showing movies (by foriegn key).  Then have all details of that movie in the Movie service.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with microservices that cascade to introduce more complexity to your data.  Have a movies service to list individual movies.  Have a Cinemas service which knows which movies are playing in which cinemas.  Make an endpoint in the cinemas service to get all the movies playing at cinema X.  The Cinemas service would query for the Cinema named within its own data, and then query the Movies service for movie details matching the foreign key of the movies playing at the cinema.  The return values from the cinema service is enriched with details from the Movie service.

When you extend this idea to countries, it still works - the movie is defined in a single location, and the country service contains licensing information using the movie's foreign keys.

On further reflection, I would consider making the data cascade happen in a fourth microservice and leave the basic microservice queries uncomplicated (Movies, Cinemas, Countries). So have your request for combo-data go to the aggregator microservice which queries from the Cinema microservice, and then query from the Movie microservice to put results from both microservices into a single response object / list.

Answer (score 0):

You should not merge the Cinema and Movie services.  If you do, you would not be able to create a movie unless it’s showing in a Cinema.  Conversely, once a movie stops showing in the last cinema it would basically cease to exist since you would not be able to access it.